# Instantly regretting transferring to new team

Tags: software-industry, united-states, new-job, internal-transfer, new-manager

I was hired as a software engineer at a tech company. After a couple weeks into my job, another manager unexpectedly reached out and asked if I wanted to transfer to work on *[insert cool new technology that will also benefit the company and you]*. I decided to transfer, but a few days into the new team, I'm regretting my decision. I liked my original team, and it turns out I probably won't be working on the new tech that much anytime soon.

In retrospect, I should have been more diligent and spent more time making the decision. Is it worth talking to either managers and ask to transfer back to the old team? Or is this a bad idea and I should just stick things out for a while, learn from the challenges/experience, and perhaps ask for a transfer down the road?

I feel like if I ask to transfer now, the impact (time they spent ramping me up) is low, but asking for reassignment so soon would also reflect poorly on me and my stability.

Comment: We don't know your managers. We can't answer  whether you can get away with this. But changing your mind after only a few days really is not a good look. I'd suggest not jumping again until months have gone by, maybe a year. Who knows, you may find there's plenty to keep you amused.

Comment: Regret isn't helpful. Saying what kinds of things you were hoping to focus on, and asking whether your assignments can be tilted in that direction, is more useful. Don't complain; look for solutions.

Comment: @keshlam True. Asking to move back may be creating a problem for their new manager; they'll be short staffed.  As you say, managers like us to take them solutions rather than problems.

Comment: Agreed. It is *much* too soon to talk about moving back; focus on moving forward.

Answer (score 35):

> After a couple weeks into my job another manager unexpectedly reached out and asked if I wanted to transfer ...

> a few days into the new team ...

Couple of weeks into a job are barely enough to understand the very basic of that job: which floor you work in, how to get there from the entrance, where are the coffee machines and the toilets, that kind of stuff. It's not remotely close to be enough to get a good understanding of the work itself and the environment.

You left that job with just a sprinkle of ideas of what it might have looked like, and now after few days you have already decided that the new team is worse than the previous one.

I think you should let some time pass and make a judgment based on some concrete experience, not rush a decision based on the confusion in which you are as a complete newbie.

When I started in a previous job in the span of the first 4 weeks I was first assigned to cool technology A, then mature tech B, then A again, then given project C which was cross technology. Did I like/dislike any of them? I cannot tell, I was just busy trying to float in the flood of information I was getting.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. It took me 4 weeks to almost quit a 4 months internship. Guess what ... It didn't get any better.

Comment: @DonQuiKong I once quite an internship after 2 weeks, after finding out I was lied to on multiple fronts. Not all situations are similar. I've stayed after making a bad decision as well. Staying after making a bad decision has helped me tremendously later in life, knowing when to stay and when to walk away.